# How to determine if a url is an image or not?

Tags: php

i want to know from the syntax if a url is a picture or not.
example: http://www.blah.com/plo52.jpg or png or gif will return true.
if the url is ending with other extension, the function will return false.

Thanks

Comment: The extension won't tell you whether or not it's actually an image.

Answer (score 14):

Check for the mime-type of the file.

Comment: But that requires to fetch the file. The OP wanted to know from the **syntax** wether it is an image or not. Nevertheless your answer is right of course.

Comment: You're right. My bad. Anyway `'/\.(png|jpg|gif|bmp)$/i'` is not a good (safe) way either, but it is faster & easier of course.

Comment: You could just do a HEAD request.

Answer (score 8):

This won't tell you if it's *really* an image. This will only tell you what it *appears* to be according to the url:

```
$url = "http://somedomain.com/images/kittens.jpg";
if(preg_match("/\.(png|jpeg|jpg|gif|bmp)$/i", $url)) {
  print "Appears to be an image";
} else {
  print "Not an image.";
}
```

Outputs:

```
    Appears to be an image
```

Note that if you expect to see images fed through .php scripts or .aspx scripts, this method will fail. To have a truly-reliable test, you'll need to check the mime-type.

Comment: +1, sometimes you have to implement something simple and effective, checking mime types might be great, but its overkill imo....

Comment: Many image hosting sites serve an HTML page for URLs ending in image file extensions

Comment: `if(preg_match('/\.(png|jpg|gif|bmp)$/i', $url))` should do it, as `preg_match` returns `0` (`False`) if it doesn't match and `1` else (no need to examine `$matches`). You forgot quotations marks around the expression and I would put `\.` at the beginning so that it does not match e.g. `foo.apng`. +1

Answer (score 5):

I suggest making a **HTTP HEAD** Request so you won't need to download the entire image, and then based on the string returned parse and make sure the Content-Type is an `image/jpeg`, `image/pjpeg`, `image/gif`, `image/png` or similar image Content-Types.

```
<?php

function parseImage( $url ) {
        $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20 );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );

    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true );

    $content = curl_exec( $ch );

    var_dump($content);
    curl_close($ch);
}

parseImage('http://sstatic.net/so/img/logo.png');
```

Returns

> string 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>
> Cache-Control: max-age=604800
>
> Content-Length: 3438
>
> Content-Type: image/png
>
> Last-Modified: Sun, 10 Jan 2010
>   09:14:52 GMT
>
> Accept-Ranges: bytes
>
> ETag: "32741b5ed591ca1:0"
>
> Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
>
> Date: Wed, 13 Jan 2010 20:37:47 GMT
>
> ' (length=256)

The Content-Type header can be spoofed, sure.. but 99% of the time it won't be, which is why this method is reliable.

Comment: Content type in the response can be falsified.

Answer (score 3):

Non-image URLs could still stream back images.  For example, an ashx or asp URL could return you image data.  The best way is to check the MIME type, Response.ContentType.

Comment: I upvoted, but even the content type in the response can be falsified or just wrong.

Answer (score 2):

If you really need  to be 100% sure, you need to download the resource and check it using [**getimagesize()**](http://de3.php.net/getimagesize).

Comment: This is what I was thinking about, but he wants a syntax checking. +1 though.

Answer (score 1):

I upvoted the preg solution, but if you really, REALLY want to know then download the file and interrogate using system functions (e.g. for linux use `file` via exec).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pathinfo](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) for getting the extension:

```
echo pathinfo('http://www.blah.com/plo52.jpg', PATHINFO_EXTENSION); // jpg
```

then wrap it into a function

```
function hasExtension($uri, array $extensions = array('jpg','gif','png'))
{
    return in_array(pathinfo($uri, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $extensions);
}

hasExtension('http://www.blah.com/plo52.jpg'); // true
```

This will also work on regular file paths and by being able to pass the $extension array you are not limited to the regex pattern. Note the function is case sensitive though.

See this question and answers for [how to best determine the MimeType of a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006632/php-how-can-i-check-if-a-file-is-mp3-or-image-file/2006664#2006664):

Answer (score 1):

Use headers_list and then check the Content-Type http://php.net/manual/en/function.headers-list.php

Comment: You probably mean `get_headers()`. `header_list` returns the headers that have been **sent** from your server