# how to check a file path is an image or not in php?

Tags: php, filepath

I have a table that stores file paths of images.documents,pdf etc... My query is

```
Select File_Paths from Uploads
```

Now how do I check whether the file path is image or not using PHP... If it is an image i have to view it or else download it.......

Comment: See this related questions and it's answers to learn how to determine the MimeType of a file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006632/php-how-can-i-check-if-a-file-is-mp3-or-image-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [file info](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php) functions.

Comment: Other than the examples at that link?

Comment: are file_info functions your typical choice in determining image types? I see MIME type is deprecated.

Comment: @rrrfusco: `mime_content_type()` is deprecated. The other functions are not.

Answer (score 3):

Good old [getimagesize()](http://es.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) is a reasonable way to find out whether a file contains a valid image. You just need to test its return value against `FALSE`:

```
<?php

$is_picture = getimagesize($filename)!==FALSE;

?>
```

Of course, it's a good idea to do it only once and store the result into the database.

If this is not what you're looking for, please clarify.

Comment: Worth noting that getimagesize() will throw exceptions if the file is not readable, so even better is to do: `$is_picture = is_file($filename) && is_readable($filename) && getimagesize($filename)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to check their extentions like this:

```
if (strpos($File_Paths, 'jpg') !== false || strpos($File_Paths, 'gif') !== false)
{
  // yes there is an image.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can chack extensions of the paths from the query. For example(using MySQL):

```
$result = mysql_query('Select File_Paths from Uploads');
$extArray = array('gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');
while ($row=mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
  $extension = substr($row[0], strrpos($row[0], ".")+1);
  if (in_array($extension, $extArray)) {
    // Do something with image
  }
  else {
    // Download other files
  }
}
```