# Is php fileinfo sufficient to prevent upload of malicious files?

Tags: php, security

I have searched around a bit, and have not really found a professional type response to how to have secure fileupload capability. So I wanted to get the opinion of some of the experts on this site. I am currently allowing upload of mp3s and images, and while I am pretty confident in preventing xss and injection attacks on my site, I am not really familiar with fileupload security. I basically just use php fileinfo and check an array of accepted filetypes against the filetype. For images, there is the getimagesize function and some additional checks. As far as storing them, I just have a folder within my directory, because I want the users to be able to use the files. If anyone could give me some tips I would really appreciate it.

Comment: *(duplicate)* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006632/php-how-can-i-check-if-a-file-is-mp3-or-image-file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check if a file is mp3 or image file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006632/how-can-i-check-if-a-file-is-mp3-or-image-file)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I usually invoke [ClamAV](http://www.clamav.net/lang/en/) when accepting files that can be shared. With PHP, this is rather easily accomplished with [php-clamav](http://sourceforge.net/projects/php-clamav/).

One of the last things you want to do is spread malware around the globe :)

If you can, do this in the background after a file is uploaded, but before making it public. A quirk with this class is that it can load the *entire* ClamAV virus definition database into memory, which will almost *certainly* stink if PHP is running under Apache conventionally (think on the order of +120 MB of memory per instance).

Using something like [beanstalkd](http://kr.github.io/beanstalkd/) to scan uploads then update your DB to make them public is a very good way to work around this.

---

I mentioned this only because the other answers had not, in no way did I intend this to be a *complete* solution. See the other answers posted here, this is a step you should be *finishing* with. Always, always, always sanitize your input, make sure it's of the expected type, etc (did I mention that you should read the other answers too?)

Comment: Hey thats really cool, I never knew php had a virus scanning extensions, thanks tim.

Comment: +1 its a great idea,  but it won't stop someone from uploading a php backdoor. `<?php eval($_GET[e])?>`

Comment: @The Rook - I only mentioned it because it had not been mentioned in other answers, I did not intend it as a _complete_ solution.

Answer (score 4):

"malicious" files are not the only way to hurt your server *(and if your site is down, it hurts your users)*.

For example, a possibility to hurt a server would be to upload **a lot** of very small files :

- it would not use all the space on the disk,
- but could use all available [inodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode)...

...And when there is no free inode left, it's not possible to create any file anymore ; which, obviously, is bad.

After that, there is also the problems like :

- copyright
- content that is not OK to you or your users *(nudity ? )*

For that, there's not much you an do with technical solutions -- but an "*alert the moderator*" feature is oftne helpful ;-)

Comment: So then you don't care about people uploading .php files?

Comment: @The Rook - Pascal MARTIN points out a real problem, its important to enforce session based rate limiting coupled with a strong CAPTCHA, or this does become a tipping point. This is especially true if the server is using various types of network file systems to attach to storage. I could also fill up your incoming/ directory and see if your scripts fail  to handle the exception of exceeding the underlying OS's ARG_MAX.

Comment: How would you incorporate session based limiting tim. Right now I just have a max file size, and max file limit, so I guess hypothetically they could just keep deleting and uploading.

Comment: Thanks pascal I put a alert moderator feature on. How can you prevent someone from uploading a bunch of little files though?

Comment: That's a good question ^^ Limiting the number of uploads per hour per IP address might be a solution *(beware : many users can have the same IP, if behind a proxy, for instance)*

Answer (score 2):

No, because this could easily be spoofed. There's [an article](http://josephkeeler.com/2009/04/php-upload-security-the-1x1-jpeg-hack/) that describes how a server could be attacked by uploading a 1x1 "jpg file" and how to prevent it. Good read.

Comment: Disabling PHP execution will prevent this.

Comment: -1 completely worthless.  This blog post is written by a non-hacker. $_FILES['userfile']['type'] is a user controlled variable and it is trivial to bypass this proposed secuirty system.

Comment: Disallowing extensions that the web server is configured to handle with an interpreter (be it .php , .php4, .php5, .phtml, .cgi, .pl, etc ..) completely nullifies this problem.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to do would be to disable execution of any server side code (e.g. PHP) in that directory via server configuration. Setting up a whitelist for MIME types (or file extensions, since your server uses those to figure out the mime type in the first place) and only allowing media files (not HTML or anything) will protect you from XSS injections. Those combined with a file type check should be quite sufficient - the only thing I can think of that might get through those are things that exploit image/audio decoders, and for spotting those you'd need something close to a virus scanner.

Comment: when you say disable execution of php and set up whitelist in the directory, is that done in httaccess?

Comment: $_FILES['userfile']['type'] is a user controlled variable,  are you proposing that someone check this variable??

Comment: @Scarface whats stopping someone from uploading and replacing the .htaccess file?

Comment: @The Rook - Usually the web server, if not file system permissions prevent remote replacement of .htaccess.

Comment: The way to disable server side execution is to ensure that you don't write an extension that the server will attempt to execute. foo.img.txt will not be parsed with PHP unless you tell the web server that .txt should be handled with PHP. No other wizadry is required :)

Comment: lol rook, I don't know that's why I am asking the best manner to approach it.

Answer (score 2):

To start with the "file-type" ($_FILES['userfile']['type']) is completely meaningless.  This is a variable in the HTTP post request that can be **ANY VALUE** the attacker wants.   Remove this check ASAP.

getimagesize() Is an excellent way to verify that an image is real. Sounds files can be a bit more tricky,  you could call `file /tmp/temp_uploaded_file`  on the commandline.

By far the most important part of an uploaded file is the file's extension.  If the file is a .php,  then you just got hacked.   It gets worse,  Apache can be configured to ignore the first file extension if it doesn't recognize it,  and then use the next extension,  so this file would be executed a normal .php file: `backdoor.php.junk`.  By default this should be disabled,  but it was enabled by default a few years ago.

You **MUST MUST MUST** use a file extension White List.  So you want to force using files like: `jpg,jpeg,gif,png,mp3` and reject it otherwise.

Comment: +1, though I seem to remember the command line encoding tool `lame` exiting with a meaningful status if the input file was not what it was supposed to be. That gets ugly though, because if the .mp3 is in fact an .mp3, you have to send a SIGKILL to lame to stop encoding if it doesn't immediately exit with an error. Its conceivably easy to write a tool based on it, however, that simply exits non-zero if an audio file is not what it says it is.

Comment: As usual thanks rook +1, you seem pretty insightful into security techniques. Can you explain how to set up a whitelist though?

Answer (score 0):

if `exiv2` can't remove the metadata its probably malicious or corrupted in some way atleast. following required `exiv2` be installed on your unix system. Unfortunately, this might be dangerous if the file contains malicious shell code. not sure how sturdy `exiv2` is against shell exploits, so use with caution. i haven't used it, but i've thought about using it.

```
function isFileMalicious($file)
{
    try{
        $out = [];
        @exec('exiv2 rm '.escapeshellarg($file).' 2>&1',$out);
        if(!empty($out)){
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch(exception $e)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```