# Filtering malicious file types for user uploaded content

Tags: php, virus, malware

I am using a [simple file upload script](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp). The script allows file type filtering but I am unsure as to what files I should allow/disallow.

What file types should I prevent from being uploaded?

Comment: You can upload any file. Just make sure they can't be executed in the target location. I'll see whether I can dig up a duplicate

Comment: You'd probably be safer with a whitelist (list of file types that are allowed) rather than a blacklist (list of file types that aren't allowed).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent execution of uploaded php files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5885643/prevent-execution-of-uploaded-php-files)

Comment: Wouldnt someone uploading a .php then viewing it in their browser be a threat?

Comment: Related (although it's not what you're looking for): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561517/is-php-fileinfo-sufficient-to-prevent-upload-of-malicious-files

Comment: @Pekka they could execute code on the server that would delete other files?.. tons of possibilities.

Comment: @maxhud that's why you want to prevent their execution on server side, as pointed out in the dupe. But merely looking at a PHP *source* file in the browser is not a problem

Comment: Do THIS: php_flag engine off in the .htaccess (thanks pekka)

Comment: Also a good rundown http://symfony-check.org/permalink/protect-yourself-against-user-uploaded-files

Comment: And make sure you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990/what-are-the-proper-permissions-for-an-upload-folder-with-php-apache

Answer (score 1):

You should only allow types you need (whitelist). You never know what could change about your server, php, or types of files people can create and what they can do to a server.

It seems there is no reason to possibly sacrifice security in exchange for less type checking.

Answer (score 1):

Found THIS (put in .htaccess):

```
php_flag engine off
```

which 'turns off' php, so the file cannot be ran! Then you can allow upload of whatever you want

(thanks to Pekka for link)

Answer (score 1):

The mime provided in $_FILES is sent from the browser thus it is not safe to trust it.
There are other function to determine mime of the file but note, that most of them rely on the file extension. This is a poor way to determine it as I can easily rename .exe to .png and the functions will report that it's an image. I am not sure of your needs but you could limit the script to allow only image files and check if they're really images with imagemagick or gd libraries.

No file is dangerous to server as it is. However, if there is a flaw in the security that would allow to run user files ANY file might be a potential threat.

I suggest not to deny some file types but to allow a couple that users might want to upload.

Answer (score 0):

Don't make a blacklist. Instead, make a whitelist of the allowed file types.