# how to check whether file is image or video type in php version 5.2.9?

Tags: php

how to check whether file is image or video type  in php version 5.2.9

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP how can i check if a file is mp3 or image file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006632/php-how-can-i-check-if-a-file-is-mp3-or-image-file) - despite the question title a good deal of the answers given there are filetype independent

Answer (score 27):

```
$mime = mime_content_type($file);
if(strstr($mime, "video/")){
    // this code for video
}else if(strstr($mime, "image/")){
    // this code for image
}
```

Should work for most file extentions.

Answer (score 6):

See my answer to

- [How can I check if a file is a mp3 or image file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006632/php-how-can-i-check-if-a-file-is-mp3-or-image-file/2006664#2006664)

Example Code

```
 function getMimeType($filename)
 {
     $mimetype = false;
     if(function_exists('finfo_fopen')) {
         // open with FileInfo
     } elseif(function_exists('getimagesize')) {
         // open with GD
     } elseif(function_exists('exif_imagetype')) {
        // open with EXIF
     } elseif(function_exists('mime_content_type')) {
        $mimetype = mime_content_type($filename);
     }
     return $mimetype;
 }
```

Comment: From the getimagesize docs:  "Do not use getimagesize() to check that a given file is a valid image. Use a purpose-built solution such as the Fileinfo extension instead."  https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

Comment: @StephenR The code above _does_ use the FileInfo extension when it's available as the first choice. Back in 2010 when I wrote this answer, `finfo_open` wasn't necessarily available though. It's part of PHP since 5.3.0. Before that, you had to install it via PECL. And not everyone could do that, e.g. shared hosting. So people needed a fallback. And while the other three are indeed not as reliable, they did get the job done. So I don't the see the point in pointing out that doc passage.

Answer (score 6):

I use the following code which IMO is more universal than in the first and the most upvoted answer:

```php
$mimeType = mime_content_type($filename);
$fileType = explode('/', $mimeType)[0];
```

I hope it was helpful for anyone.

Answer (score 3):

You can check the MIME type using the [`finfo_file` function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php)

Example from the help page

```
<?php
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); // return mime type ala mimetype extension
foreach (glob("*") as $filename) {
    echo finfo_file($finfo, $filename) . "\n";
}
finfo_close($finfo);
?>
```

**EDIT**: after better checking your question, this won't work, `finfo` functions require PHP 5.3.0

Answer (score 3):

```
if(isset($_FILES['my_file'])) {
$mime = $_FILES['my_file']['type'];
if(strstr($mime, "video/")){
$filetype = "video";
}else if(strstr($mime, "image/")){
$filetype = "image";
}else if(strstr($mime, "audio/")){
$filetype = "audio";
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: This answer works for uploaded files only. Also, [the `'type'` is provided by the browser (if any)](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) and therefore may not be fully trusted.

Answer (score 1):

I use this code and it works very well.

```
$mimeType = $request->images->getMimeType();
$fileType = explode('/', $mimeType)[0];
```

if it was an image, this code will give you the image word in the $fileType and if it was a video this code will give you the video word in the $fileType, then you can check on it by the if conditions.

good luck

Answer (score 0):

Rather old question, but for others looking at this in the future, I would handle this like so:

```
function getType($file): string
{
    $mime_type = mime_content_type($file);

    return strtok($mime_type, '/');
}
```

This method utilises [`strtok`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php) to return the portion of the `$mime_type` string before the first `/`.

For example, let's say `$file` has a `$mime_type` of `video/mp4`, the `getType` method will return `video`.