# identify video file in php

Tags: php, file, video, upload

I am uploading images and video from one browse button. On the backend side, I want to identify it's type whether it's video file, image or invalid file.

I checked with

```
$_FILES['name']['type']
```

for images it's ok there are 4-5 types of images we need to allow. But, for videos there are lots of types. Like in this case it's application/octet-stream

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074527/how-to-check-whether-file-is-image-or-video-type-in-php-version-5-2-9

Comment: So why not just allow most known formats like .avi, .mp4 . wmv ? There is no need to allow every single codec format.

Comment: in the file array. there is no MIME type key. I never used this thing. I think I need to look into it.

Comment: @user2831723: actually I am converting anyvideo to mp4 and then store it on server.