# PHP: "independent" function to replace mime_content_type?

Tags: php, function, verification, mime-types

Is there any available, "independent" function which could replace mime_content_type()?

On my new hosting I'm getting error:
`Fatal error: Call to undefined function mime_content_type() in download.php on line 3`

finfo_file doesn't work as well...

Comment: See my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006632/php-how-can-i-check-if-a-file-is-mp3-or-image-file/2006664#2006664

Comment: *(related)* http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Mime_type_detection#MIME_detection

Answer (score 1):

Just mimic the function in your compat.php if you have one

```
if(!function_exists("mime_content_type"))
{
    function mime_content_type($file)
    {
        $open_bit = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
        return finfo_file($open_bit, $file);
    }
}
```

The above function (`FileInfo`) is a PECL extension and is encouraged by PHP To use as an alternative, if you do not have the extension installed you can do the following:

- Find the url to the latest version of fileinfo from http://pecl.php.net/package/Fileinfo
- Download, compile and install
- Run the following commands

  - wget `http://pecl.php.net/get/Fileinfo-X.X.X.tgz`
  - gunzip Fileinfo-X.X.X.tgz
  - tar -xvf Fileinfo-X.X.X.tar
  - cd fileinfo-X.X.X
  - ./configure
  - make
  - make install
- Enable the extension by adding `extension=fileinfo.so` to your php.ini
- Restart your web server and it should be working.
  And then proceed as normal

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of fact, there are two indepent implementations. One in http://upgradephp.berlios.de/ and one in [PHP_Compat](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_Compat/redirected). You need the `mime-magic` file in either case.