# read microsoft excel, word and powerpoint info using PHP

Tags: php

i want my PHPapp to read a file and tell me if it's a word, excel or powerpoint file. my first approach was to read the extension of the file. But microsoft has different file extension names, and i was also wondering about files uploaded by a mac (with no filename extension)

So, maybe the answer is using mimetypes. Do you know a better approach for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, trying to determine the MimeType is your best bet short of just try/catching to load the files with [PHPWord](http://phpword.codeplex.com/), [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) and [PHPowerpoint](http://phppowerpoint.codeplex.com/) directly to see if they throw an exception (Mark Baker correct me please if they dont throw exceptions).

See my answer to

- [PHP how can i check if a file is mp3 or image file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006632/php-how-can-i-check-if-a-file-is-mp3-or-image-file/2006664#2006664)

for various ways to detect the MimeType.

You can find a number of possible MimeTypes for Office documents at

- http://filext.com/faq/office_mime_types.php and
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exceldev/thread/87b9cd73-a41b-4fd0-94c7-dfe53e92947e