# Is it possible read MSWORD with PHPWord?

Tags: php, ms-word, phpword

I know that PHPWord library can create a word file, But,Is it possible read word file with PHPWord? If yes, how? I saw many answers in this site about reading a word file with php. The answers was "PHPWord", one of these answers is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726786/read-microsoft-excel-word-and-powerpoint-info-using-php). But couldn't find how it's possible. I searched in PHPWord officcial site but no result.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is a simple "No". PHPWord doesn't read word documents (though it can read basic style information from a template), only writes them.

Comment: Thanks, how can i read word file with php? i want to parse word/document.xml with simplexml_load_file, but it's empty. I want read not only the content, i want to know which tag the text in? Sorry my english.

Comment: This is incorrect. [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord) itself says: "PHPWord is a library written in pure PHP that provides a set of classes to write to *and read from* different document file formats."

Comment: @LincolnBergeson - It was correct at the time when the answer was written, nearly 4 years ago: I apologise that PHPWord has been developed further since then to support reading as well... memo to self, don't bother adding new functionality to PHPOffice

Comment: @MarkBaker Didn't mean to sound harsh. I just put that there for future readers. No ill will intended :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at this question:
[read word document in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646445/read-word-document-in-php)

It provides some insides on how to read a docx-document in PHP.