# simple PHP file upload more secure

Tags: php, upload, die

I have this (very simple) PHP upload script:

```
$pic=$_FILES['photo']['name'];
$picc=$_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];
$tar="".$pic;
move_uploaded_file($picc,$tar);
 $fileName = $_FILES['photo']['name'];
```

How would I go about making the script `die` if it isn't an `image` file, or if it exceeds `1 mb`?

Thanks a heck in advance! :)

Comment: To check whether file is an image see this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006632/php-how-can-i-check-if-a-file-is-mp3-or-image-file

Comment: `$_FILES['photo']['size']`?

Comment: @Supericy what masurement is this in?

Comment: @SolèneLeVan My guess would be bytes. Just upload a file you know the size of and print it out.

Answer (score 1):

To check whether file is an image see this question:

[PHP how can i check if a file is mp3 or image file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006632/php-how-can-i-check-if-a-file-is-mp3-or-image-file)

To check filesize see this tutorial:

http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/3.html