# PHP - remove items that are not image from array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this function to get items from directory:

```
if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
                $images = array();

                while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
                    if (!is_dir($dir.$file)) {
                        $images[] = $file;
                    }
                }

                closedir($dh);
            }

        return $images;
```

The function is working, and I am getting this result (this is a test directory):

```
array (size=9)
  0 => string 'odluka o matinim podrujima.shs' (length=31)
  1 => string 'Odluka o optinskoj upravi.doc' (length=29)
  2 => string 'o_pirotu3.jpg' (length=13)
  3 => string 'o_pirotu4.jpg' (length=13)
  4 => string 'Panorama 10.jpg' (length=15)
  5 => string 'Panorama 8n.jpg' (length=15)
  6 => string 'Panorama n.jpg' (length=14)
  7 => string 'PRAVILNIK O ORGANIZACIJI I SISTEMATIZACIJI POSLOVA.doc' (length=54)
  8 => string 'Pravilnik_o_reprezentaciji.doc' (length=30)
```

How can I remove all non images items, and is there some way for me to choose mime type that will stay in returned array (I need jpg, png, and bmp)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than removing non-images, why not just not add them in the first place?

```
...
if( !is_dir($dir.$file)) {
    if( preg_match("/\.(png|gif|jpe?g|bmp)/",$file,$m)) {
        // $m[1] is now the extension of the filename
        // You can perform additional verification
        // Example: if $m[1] == 'png' check if imagecreatefrompng accepts it
        $images[] = $file;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is working like a charm :). One quick question (my knowledge on regular expression is very limited ) - does this expression covers small and capital letters (PNG and png are the same)?

Comment: Add `i` right after the last `/` in the preg_match regex, this will allow case to not matter.

Comment: Thank you a lot mate :). You helped me more then you know :).

Answer (score 0):

```
string mime_content_type ( string $filename ) 
Returns the MIME content type for a file as determined by using information from the magic.mime file.
```

or

```
mixed strpos ( string $haystack , mixed $needle [, int $offset = 0 ] )
Find the numeric position of the first occurrence of needle in the haystack string.
```

Are the functions you search.

Answer (score 0):

Google is your friend ...

```
function is_image($path)
{
    $a = getimagesize($path);
    $image_type = $a[2];

    if(in_array($image_type , array(IMAGETYPE_GIF , IMAGETYPE_JPEG ,IMAGETYPE_PNG , IMAGETYPE_BMP)))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting files that are images in PHP is a difficult task. If those are untrusted files, then you had better do a lot of research on how you are going to approach that sanitizing of those images, and in particular, MIME type filtering and extension filtering are just not good enough. Neither is `getimagesize()`, really.

However, if there is no chance of untrusted files in those directories, then you can simply extension filter, by checking the end of their filenames for their respective extensions. Or, use PHP's `getimagesize()` function and see if returns anything, but that will give you more than just your specified image formats.

See [PHP how can i check if a file is mp3 or image file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006632/php-how-can-i-check-if-a-file-is-mp3-or-image-file) for more about MIME-types and detecting images.